# List all folder and subfolder inside it where folder names start with a* or b* or c* with path

Tags: linux

I need a folder and subfolder inside it to be displayed where names that start with A* or B* or C* and display along with path

Below Command Does not Display as expected

```
$ ls -l | egrep d
```

Comment: What part of this command is supposed to limit the starting letter of the names?

Comment: @Scott Hunter : it should display with path of that folder : like => D:/Tem/C , D:/Temp/A

Comment: That is what you want; it doesn't say what part of your posted code is trying to accomplish it, which is what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the current directory by using the system environment variable PWD. You can combine the PWD with your ls command

using ls -ld

```
ls -ld $PWD/A* $PWD/B* $PWD/C*
```

EDIT

If you want a list of all the directories and sub directories you can use the find command.

```
find . > subfolders.txt && cat subfolders.txt | egrep -i "^./E|^./g"
```

This command will recursively list all contents on your current working directory and send the output to a txt file named subfolders.txt. Then it will read the contents of subfolders.txt and using egrep, you can filter out anything that starts with "./E" or "./g". the -i option means it is case insensitive.

NOTE: This will also display the files contained in those subfolders.

Comment: it should display with path of that folder : like => D:/Tem/C , D:/Temp/A @Sudosu0

Comment: half working bro @Sudosu0 I need the list of subfolders also not only main folder like main folder + inside folder list + in that if any folder list depending upon keyword start with A B or C

Comment: Okay so @openxxs was on the right path with that one. updating answer

Answer (score 0):

```
find . | grep -E '/A|/B|/C'
```

find is better than ls for your requirements.

Comment: Why would `find` be better here? In fact, this command does something completely different, since it lists all nested paths.